# Documenting Python parameters in docstring using PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm having some trouble figuring out the proper way to document a method in Pycharm to achieve type hints AND parameter description.

In [Pycharm's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) it suggests:

> :param "type_name" "param_name": "param_description"

(1) However, when I try to use that, the function definition does not properly show the parameter description:

[image]

(2) If I switch to leading with the `@` sign I get a list of parameters and their types, but I do not get the parameter description:

[image]

(3) If I stick with the `@` sign and drop the types, I get the parameter descriptions:

[image]

(4) If I explicitly add `@type` for each `@param` (which completely blows up the size of the comment block), everything works properly (but I hate the size of the comment):

[image]

(5) Finally, for sake of completeness, using `:` instead of `@` causes everything to fail to populate:

[image]

Note that I have tried changing the documentation system within Pycharm, but it doesn't affect how it renders the documentation -- it only seems to affect how it autopopulates a comment block for you.

How can I achieve documentation as close to example (1) which is compact, but actually have it populate the function definition properly?  I'd hate to be stuck with style (4).

Comment: Please note that for Python 3 you can use native Python annotation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/ - a feature which will receive update in Python 3.5

Comment: Didn't know that it worked with @

Comment: Oddly enough, I found out that when the documentation is generated by typing """ then toggling auto-complete, PyCharm seems to recognize example 5.

Answer (score 12):

Have you checked <kbd>Settings...</kbd> - <kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Python integrated tools</kbd> - <kbd>Docstring format</kbd>? You can choose the parsing style.

You can choose from:

- Plain
- Epytext
- reStructuredText
- Numpy
- Google

Comment: Select reStructuredText for `:param` format. Works for me 

Answer (score 4):

**Copied straight** from [Pycharm: Auto generate `:type param:` field in docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069526/pycharm-auto-generate-type-param-field-in-docstring):

---

Per [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/documenting-source-code-in-pycharm.html):

> If [configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/enabling-creation-of-documentation-comments.html), the documentation comment stubs can be generated
>   with `type` and `rtype` tags.

Following the link:

> ...
>
> 3. In the [Smart Keys](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/smart-keys.html) page, select the check box **Insert 'type' and
>      'rtype' to the documentation comment stub**.

Once you have done this, put the cursor in a parameter name in the definition, activate the Smart Keys feature (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, by default) and select **Specify type for reference in docstring**. This will insert the appropriate comment line . Similarly you can put the cursor in the function/method name and select **Specify return type in docstring**.

---

So now if you type `"""` after a function declaration it creates them automatically for you:

```
def funct(a, b, c):
    """

    :param a: 
    :type a: 
    :param b: 
    :type b: 
    :param c: 
    :type c: 
    :return: 
    :rtype: 
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on the latest version of PyCharm (2016.2 CE) and even in some previous patched versions.

[it works! (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCwwv.png)

I asked similar question and got an answer!

[PyCharm and reStructuredText (Sphinx) documentation popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235275/pycharm-and-restructuredtext-sphinx-documentation-popups)