# Can I avoid variable type field in Pycharm Docstrings?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, restructuredtext

I am using [Pycharm  Docstrings reStructuredText](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-documentation-comments.html#d7d90883) to document my code, and I was wondering whether the *variable type* in the function documentation can be omitted automatically, let's say I have this function

```
def unsignedToSigned(inputNumber,numberType):
    if(inputNumber >= 2**(numberType-1)):
        signedNumber = inputNumber - 2**numberType
    else:
        signedNumber = inputNumber
    return signedNumber
```

Automatic documentation will produce

```
 def unsignedToSigned(inputNumber,numberType):
        '''  
        :param inputNumber: 
        :type inputNumber: 
        :param numberType: 
        :type numberType: 
        :return: 
        :rtype: 
        '''
        if(inputNumber >= 2**(numberType-1)):
            signedNumber = inputNumber - 2**numberType
        else:
            signedNumber = inputNumber
        return signedNumber
```

However, I am looking for having something akin to below

```
 def unsignedToSigned(inputNumber,numberType):
        '''  
        :param inputNumber: 
        :param numberType: 
        :return: 
        '''
        if(inputNumber >= 2**(numberType-1)):
            signedNumber = inputNumber - 2**numberType
        else:
            signedNumber = inputNumber
        return signedNumber
```

Thus, I may keep consistency with prior code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By digging a bit, and thanks to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915882/1757475)  I found the solution, which is

> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Python -> Untick
>   *Insert type placeholders in the documentation stub*

Cheers