# How does "Insert documentation comment stub" work in Pycharm for getting method parameters?

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I have enabled *Insert documentation comment stub* within `Editor | General |Smart keys` :

[image: smart keys settings]

But then how to get the method parameters type stubs? Adding the docstring triple quotes and then enter does open up the docstring - but with nothing in it:

```py
def get_self_join_clause(self, df, alias1='o', alias2 = 'n'):
    """
    
    """   # pycharm added this automatically
```

Comment: The IDE settings themselves are shown in the 1st linked thread of the answer, so I won't reproduce them here. What is worth noting at present is that the type placeholders won't be populated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get the method parameters type stubs?

PyCharm does [generate the docstring stub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31069526) with the type placeholders, but the placeholders aren't currently (using PyCharm 2022.1) populated from the [`__annotations__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations) with the types. This has been marked with the state *"To be discussed"* in the JetBrains bugtracker, see issues [PY-23400](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23400) and [PY-54930](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54930).

Inclusion of the type placeholders is configured by checking `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Smart Keys` `>` `Python` `>` `Insert type placeholders in the documentation comment stub`.

---

---

It's worth noting the insert docstring stub intention is selected on the function name itself

[image: function in editor with intention]

In this example with [Napoleon style docstring format](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html) selected in `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Python Integrated Tools` `>` `Docstrings`, the result:

[image: editor after docstring stub insertion]